# Inference result with .pb file does not match with .h5

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I have trying to deploy my ai-model to GCP's AI-Platform, and looks like I'm succeed, but the inference result is incorrect compare to local h5 model inference result.

I'm using tensorflow==1.2.1, Keras==2.0.6, Python 3.5.3 now.

I used `K.set_learning_phase()` to distinguish training/inference phase, re-created my model using previous config/weights, saved the new model by SavedModelBuilder.

```py
def save_model_for_production(model, version, path='prod_models'):
    K.set_learning_phase(0)  # all new operations will be in test mode from now on

    # serialize the model and get its weights, for quick re-building
    config = model.get_config()
    weights = model.get_weights()

    # re-build a model where the learning phase is now hard-coded to 0

    new_model = model.from_config(config)
    # from keras.models import model_from_config
    # new_model = model_from_config(config)
    # new_model = Model.from_config(config)
    new_model.set_weights(weights)


    model_input = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(new_model.input)   # deprecated
    model_output = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(new_model.output)

    prediction_signature = (
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_INPUTS: model_input},
            outputs={tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_OUTPUTS: model_output},
            method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

    with K.get_session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        #init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
        #sess.run(init_op)
        #sess.run(tf.saved_model.main_op.main_op())

        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)

        export_path = os.path.join(
            tf.compat.as_bytes(path),
            tf.compat.as_bytes(version))
        builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess=sess, tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                'predict':
                   prediction_signature
            })
        builder.save()
```

I guess that variable was not initialized correctly. I tried several `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, `tf.local_variables_initializer()` , etc and the inference result is different each other. (e.g. [1.0], [0.0], [3.2314555e-13])

But I did not get the right results with anything.

If anyone knows how to solve this, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this problem have been resolved.

I didn't call any initializer(e.g. `tf.global_variables_initializer`), then model works correctly.

I can not explain exactly why, but when use `K.get_session()` for getting session, variable initialization is not needed I guess.